# How to simulate a keypress in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I simulate a backtab in a js/jquery function?

I have a select2 function (Version: 3.4.6) with multiple selection, and it skips to to next field when I make a selection.

I have tried things like

```
$("[name=" + i + "]").select2('open');
```

and it doesn't work.

If I press a backtab the function does what I need. How do I simulate that?

Comment: Have you tried to `preventDefault()` behaviour on select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myEvent = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 9 });
$("#myElement").trigger( myEvent );
```

Comment: Could you please provide some explanation? Just for the people who are new to the Javascript/jQuery language.